# Как убрать элементы из списка

Tags: python

Всем добрый вечер. Подскажите, какой есть самый быстрый способ из такого списка:

```
['a', '', 'b', '', 'c', '', 'd', '', 'e', '', 'f', '']
```

сделать такой, то есть без '   ':

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Какая есть альтернатива этому способу? Т.е. без еще одного списка?

```
for i in listt:
    if i != '':
        new_list.append(i)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Можно воспользоваться del, но что если элементы не упорядочены?

Comment: Не надо `del`, опять придётся приколы объяснять, почему не все элементы обработались! ))  Сколько можно уже ))

Comment: сейчас попробовал и с del, также пустые пробелы убрались. Но эт сработает если элементы строго по одному правилу расположены в списке :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
items = ['ivan_p', '', 'petr_i', '', 'ivan_p1', '', 'ivan_i', '', 'ivan_i1', '', 'ivan_i2', '']
```

Через функциональный стиль:

```
items = list(filter(None, items))
```

Через удаление:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(items))):
    # Или: 
    # if not items[i]:
    if items[i] == '':
        items.pop(i)
```

Comment: Прикольно, не знал про параметр `None`

Answer (score 3):

Можно используя comprehensions:

```
items = ['ivan_p', '', 'petr_i', '', 'ivan_p1', '', 'ivan_i', '', 'ivan_i1', '', 'ivan_i2', '']
[x for x in items if x != '']
```

Comment: `[x for x in items if x]` ?

Comment: Так удалит еще и `None`. Не знаю хочет ли такое ТС.

Answer (score 0):

Можно короче, с использованием STEP:

```
items = ['ivan_p', '', 'petr_i', '', 'ivan_p1', '', 'ivan_i', '', 'ivan_i1', '', 'ivan_i2', '']
items=items[::2]
```